# how can I prevent dbo login from access my database?

Tags: sql-server

I Made login (x) with sql authentication for mydatabase(Sharp)
in sql2000.And I want to prevent dbo login from access my database 
what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dbo` login is always present in every database and has implied permissions to perform all activities. See the [documentation regarding the "dbo" account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905208(SQL.80).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the "dbo" user at all.

Remember;: logins and users are different things in SQL Server and there is no "dbo" login" as such that maps to the "dbO" user anyway.

It should make no difference

Comment: thank you but I want no one connect to my data base without login that I created .when I use local server instance any can connect with the login which I created